# Understanding a newer C# Syntax

Tags: c#

In a `Try-Catch` block, there is a line of code like this:

```
Catch(Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError("Unable to get {thisOneIsaParamOK}, from network: \n {exception}", thisOneIsaParamOK, ex.Message);
}
```

I know about `string interpolation` syntax with `$` which this one doesn't have it. I can say ok the first param is fine too because it is passed in to the method `thisOneIsaParamOK` but then there is nowhere in code I can find a variable or param for `exception`  .
So I assume this is a syntax I am not familiar with.  Can someone explain it ?

I tried to convert it to a more basic string `concat` syntax.

Comment: So these are placeholders. Under the hood they are changed to "{0}", "{1}". But they also kept and propagated to logs storage. So in the logs you will be able to filter by values of "exception" and "thisOneIsaParamOK".

Comment: This style is often used by logging systems.  It's not a special syntax, that's literally just a string and additional `params` being sent to the `LogError` method.  The underlying logging system (e.g. Azure App Insights) stores the string and the parameters separately.  It can show you the resulting string, but can also show you the values independently (useful for sorting, filtering, reporting, etc.).

Comment: The first argument of that LogError methos is eventually getting converted to a string right? I want to be able to know what that string is? So when I write a unit test for it and want to compare the string, I be able to do that. But currently I don't know what this string ends up being.

Comment: As the duplicate suggests, this is about the implementation of the logging framework, not some specific C# syntax. The (extension-) method you are calling looks like this: `public static void LogError(this ILogger logger, string? message, params object?[] args)` . Under the hood, the message template gets parsed, and the placeholders are replaced. After that, it functions similarly to `string.Format`

Comment: Maybe look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line for more information about logging in C#

Comment: @LonelySemiColon: *"The first argument of that LogError methos is eventually getting converted to a string right?"* - The first argument to the `LogError` method shown **is** a string.  It doesn't need to be converted into one.  It's not clear what unit test you're referring to, but if that's what you're trying to ask about then you are encouraged to ask about that, to include a [mcve] demonstrating what you've attempting and what isn't working as expected.

Comment: yes I understood. I was so used to string interpolation syntax that I had forgot about old school string.Format one.